# Creating a Crosstab query with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, prepared-statement, dynamicquery

I am new to php and mysql and I am trying to create a crosstab query using the code below:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('SUM(IF(category = ''',category,''', duration,NULL))AS ',category)) INTO @sql

FROM tblnon_oeedata;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT productionDay, ', @sql, ' FROM tblnon_oeedata GROUP BY productionDay');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Everytime I run it I keep getting the error:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Maintenance During Production,SUM(IF(category = 'Breakdowns', duration,NULL))AS ' at line 1

How do I solve this problem, i am really stuck. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('SUM(IF(category = ''',category,''', duration,NULL))AS ''',category, '''')) INTO @sql

FROM tblnon_oeedata;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT productionDay, ', @sql, ' FROM tblnon_oeedata GROUP BY productionDay');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @saharsh it's worked thanks a million!!! Say out of curiosity why was my code not working?

Comment: You had not put quote sign in alias name of column, so the query was breaking. After putting Quote before and after of aloias name it will work

Comment: How did you used stmt with php ?

Comment: Say @SaharshShah how do I output the above code onto php or html?